# MARS for MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Today I've implemented a nasty hack in my code where *every* request to the database opens it's own connection due to the fact that I couldn't find any way to enable MARS (multiple active record sets) when communicating with a MySQL database.

In my C# program I do a lot of parallel work, which isn't a problem regarding databases such as MSSQL 2005 and 2008 (append ;MultipleActiveResultSets=true to your connection string) and SQLite (supports it "out of the box") and you are able to retrieve two datasets from the database at the same time.

Things that I do know: it's expensive to open a connection to the database and their for I would like to keep these to a minimum.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version (and connector) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a best way to handle this scenario type is to implement that parallel data processing into your database, by using a store procedure or a cursor, so you don't need to deal with a very specific database feature.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

I don't know if there really is no way to enable MARS with MySQL, but if that's correct, then my best suggestion is to implement connection-pool.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MySQL documentation for connection string parameters (no MARs) -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

> Things that I do know: it's expensive to open a connection to the database and their for I would like to keep these to a minimum.

Utilize connection pooling all the way!  (just make sure you use the exact same connection string each time).

Comment: Link dead, please fix it

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't support MARS,instead you have to save the data and close the reader or use another connection for the new reader.